# How can I achieve the below layout in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

This layout is made by me, the layout you are looking is a SVG image so I have just made the image to fill max size and added the above text and camera capture button below. But now I want to remove the image background and want to make the same layout programmatically.

[image]

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    AndroidView({ previewView }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Icon(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_card_overlay),
            contentDescription = null
        )

        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_black_transparent),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(26.dp)
    ) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(bottom = 20.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    onCloseCameraClick()
                },
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_back_ios_24),
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color.White
            )

            Text(
                text = "Passport",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }

        Text(
            text = "Place your passport inside the frame and take a\npicture.\nMake sure it is not cut or has any glare.",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 12.sp
        )
    }

    IconButton(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 20.dp),
        onClick = {
            Log.d("takePhoto", "ON CLICK")
            takePhoto(
                imageCapture = imageCapture,
                outputDirectory = outputDirectory,
                executor = executor,
                onImageCaptured = onImageCaptured,
                onError = onError
            )
        },
        content = {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_camera_24),
                contentDescription = stringResource(R.string.take_picture),
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(0.2f)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

You can see I have used ic_card_overlay image which act like a background. I want to achieve the same black transparent background with the box in the middle which will not include the black transparent color. Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove "dark" background from your picture by button click, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with using BlendMode.Clear

```
@Composable
fun TransparentClipLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    width: Dp,
    height: Dp,
    offsetY: Dp
) {

    val offsetInPx: Float
    val widthInPx: Float
    val heightInPx: Float

    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        offsetInPx = offsetY.toPx()
        widthInPx = width.toPx()
        heightInPx = height.toPx()
    }

    Canvas(modifier = modifier) {

        val canvasWidth = size.width

        with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
            val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

            // Destination
            drawRect(Color(0x77000000))

            // Source
            drawRoundRect(
                topLeft = Offset(
                    x = (canvasWidth - widthInPx) / 2,
                    y = offsetInPx
                ),
                size = Size(widthInPx, heightInPx),
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(30f,30f),
                color = Color.Transparent,
                blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
            )
            restoreToCount(checkPoint)
        }

    }
}
```

You can customize corner radius size too. This is only for demonstration

Usage

```
Column {

    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Image(
            modifier =Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        TransparentClipLayout(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            width = 300.dp,
            height = 200.dp,
            offsetY = 150.dp
        )
    }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: @Thracian can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73531243/11560810)

Comment: Is there any way I can blur the overlay part?

Answer (score 4):

You can archieve this background layout using a custom `Shape` in combination with a `Surface`. With a custom implementation you can define what parts of the `Surface` are displayed and which parts are "cut out".

The `cutoutPath` defines the part which are highlighted. Here it is defined as a `RoundRect` with a dynamically calculated position and size. Adjust the `topLeft` and ``formulas as you need.

Using `Path.combine(...)` the `outlinePath` is combined with the `cutoutPath`. This is where the magic happens.

```kotlin
/**
 * This is a shape with cuts out a rectangle in the center
 */
class CutOutShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: Density
    ): Outline {
        val outlinePath = Path()
        outlinePath.addRect(Rect(Offset(0f, 0f), size))

        val cutoutHeight = size.height * 0.3f
        val cutoutWidth = size.width * 0.75f
        val center = Offset(size.width / 2f, size.height / 2f)

        val cutoutPath = Path()
        cutoutPath.addRoundRect(
            RoundRect(
                Rect(
                    topLeft = center - Offset(
                        cutoutWidth / 2f,
                        cutoutHeight / 2f
                    ),
                    bottomRight = center + Offset(
                        cutoutWidth / 2f,
                        cutoutHeight / 2f
                    )
                ),
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(16f, 16f)
            )
        )

        val finalPath = Path.combine(
            PathOperation.Difference,
            outlinePath,
            cutoutPath
        )

        return Outline.Generic(finalPath)
    }
}
```

The shape can be used like this:

```kotlin
Surface(
    shape = CutOutShape(),
    color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.45f)
) { }
```

---

This results in the following screen:

[image]

```kotlin
Box {
    AndroidView({ previewView }, modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize())

    Surface(
        shape = CutOutShape(),
        color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.45f),
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) { }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 54.dp, start = 32.dp, end = 32.dp, bottom = 54.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.TwoTone.ArrowBack,
                    contentDescription = null,
                    tint = Color.White
                )
            }

            Text(
                "Passport",
                color = Color.White,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )
        }

        Text(
            "Place your passport inside the frame and take a picture.\nMake sure it is not cut or has any glare.",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 12.sp
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))

        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.TwoTone.Camera,
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(48.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @Bennik2000 can you please help me on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73531243/11560810)

Comment: Hey can I use the  CutOutShape() to align images as well, My requirement is same just I've to add multiple Icons above and below the cutout part, It'll be difficult as cutout and Icons can overlap, Any suggestion?