# How can I only capture the image which is shown inside the box in android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

How can I only capture the image which is shown inside the box in this camera overlay. I am able to get the bitmap of the image successfully.

[image]

I can get the position of the box by this

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_background_round),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->

                    val rect = coordinates.boundsInRoot()
                    rectTopLeft = rect.topLeft
                    rectBottomRight = rect.bottomRight     
                 
                })
```

Comment: That's some good UI, sir.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a new bitmap will return a portion of original image in Rectangle shape not in a **custom shape**. Very likely reason you get that exception is difference between Composable and Bitmap dimensions. When you crop an image on a Composable you need to interpolate left and size of Composable to Bitmap left and size.

What this means is let's say your image is 1000x1000px while your screen is 2000x2000px

if you wish to get (200,200) position with 1000px width/height on Composable you get it as

val actualLeft =left* (bitmapWidth/composableWidth)
200*(1000/2000) = 100 should be the coordinate of left position on image. Same goes for y coordinate, width and height.

What you actually ask is image cropper with shape minus gestures. As i answered in [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533016/how-can-i-achieve-the-below-layout-in-jetpack-compose/73533699#73533699) you need to use Canvas. But this time Canvas should be

```
androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas
```

And pass your Image as

```
    val canvas: androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas = Canvas(imageBitmap)
```

and

```
canvas.apply {
        drawRoundedRect(
           // properties
            paint = paint
        )
    }
```

then draw the shape, and convert it to a path since we need to use it in this Canvas with a Paint. This Paint should have XferMode.SrcIn. I will update this answer when i'm available. You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168588/jetpack-compose-androidx-compose-ui-graphics-canvas-not-refreshing-correctly-for), `NativeCanvasSample2`is very similar to what you wish to achieve except what i want to achieve is a cropper gestures.

I made a workaround and sample that how you can clip with a shape `SrcIn` with compose Canvas or using scaling and interpolation to correctly clip an image using `rectDraw` and `rectCrop`.

```
@Composable
fun TransparentClipLayout(
    modifier: Modifier,
    imageBitmap: ImageBitmap,
    width: Dp,
    height: Dp,
    offsetY: Dp,
    crop: Boolean = false,
    onCropSuccess: (ImageBitmap) -> Unit
) {

    val offsetInPx: Float
    val widthInPx: Float
    val heightInPx: Float

    with(LocalDensity.current) {
        offsetInPx = offsetY.toPx()
        widthInPx = width.toPx()
        heightInPx = height.toPx()
    }

    BoxWithConstraints(modifier) {

        val composableWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        val composableHeight = constraints.maxHeight


        val widthRatio = imageBitmap.width / composableWidth.toFloat()
        val heightRatio = imageBitmap.height / composableHeight.toFloat()

        val rectDraw = remember {
            Rect(
                offset = Offset(
                    x = (composableWidth - widthInPx) / 2f,
                    y = offsetInPx
                ),
                size = Size(widthInPx, heightInPx)
            )
        }

        val rectCrop by remember {
            mutableStateOf(
                IntRect(
                    offset = IntOffset(
                        (rectDraw.left * widthRatio).toInt(),
                        (rectDraw.top * heightRatio).toInt()
                    ),
                    size = IntSize(
                        (rectDraw.width * widthRatio).toInt(),
                        (rectDraw.height * heightRatio).toInt()
                    )
                )
            )
        }

        LaunchedEffect(crop) {
            if (crop) {
                delay(500)
                val croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    imageBitmap.asAndroidBitmap(),
                    rectCrop.left,
                    rectCrop.top,
                    rectCrop.width,
                    rectCrop.height
                ).asImageBitmap()

                onCropSuccess(croppedBitmap)
            }
        }

        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

            if (!crop) {
                drawImage(
                    image = imageBitmap,
                    dstSize = IntSize(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt())
                )
            }

            with(drawContext.canvas.nativeCanvas) {
                val checkPoint = saveLayer(null, null)

                if (!crop) {
                    // Destination
                    drawRect(Color(0x77000000))

                    // Source
                    drawRoundRect(
                        topLeft = rectDraw.topLeft,
                        size = rectDraw.size,
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(30f, 30f),
                        color = Color.Transparent,
                        blendMode = BlendMode.Clear
                    )

                } else {
                    // Destination
                    drawRoundRect(
                        topLeft = rectDraw.topLeft,
                        size = rectDraw.size,
                        cornerRadius = CornerRadius(30f, 30f),
                        color = Color.Red,
                    )

                    // Source
                    drawImage(
                        image = imageBitmap,
                        dstSize = IntSize(size.width.toInt(), size.height.toInt()),
                        blendMode = BlendMode.SrcIn
                    )
                }

                restoreToCount(checkPoint)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var croppedImage by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }

var crop by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var showDialog by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

val imageBitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1)

Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    TransparentClipLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        imageBitmap = imageBitmap,
        width = 300.dp,
        height = 200.dp,
        offsetY = 150.dp,
        crop = crop,
        onCropSuccess = {
            croppedImage = it
            crop = false
            showDialog = true
        }
    )

    Button(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(20.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .align(Alignment.BottomStart),
        onClick = { crop = true }) {
        Text("Capture")
    }

    if (showDialog) {
        croppedImage?.let {
            ShowCroppedImageDialog(
                imageBitmap = it
            ) {
                showDialog = !showDialog
                croppedImage = null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dialog

```
@Composable
fun ShowCroppedImageDialog(imageBitmap: ImageBitmap, onDismissRequest: () -> Unit) {
    androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        text = {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
                bitmap = imageBitmap,
                contentDescription = "result"
            )
        },
        confirmButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onDismissRequest()
                }
            ) {
                Text("Confirm")
            }
        },
        dismissButton = {
            TextButton(
                onClick = {
                    onDismissRequest()
                }
            ) {
                Text("Dismiss")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Result

[image]

In result the one in screen is due to `BlendMode.SrcIn` if you fusion with the Canvas that takes image you will be able to get it. The one in dialog is the actual one because of cropping image. As i mentioned above you can crop images with a Rectangle.

You need to implement Canvas(bitmap) for custom shapes as in my question, i might update this answer with  `androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas = Canvas(imageBitmap)` when i'm available in the future, i faced some issues but will fix them soon. This is basically how to build an image cropper with shape and crop after scaling in Bitmap dimensions.

Comment: Dr. Thrace, you put in a great effort in answering even the most minor of the questions. I appreciate that,

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper if you are talking about this question this what i'm actually working on. I'm building an image cropper. And this is how you build one in most simplistic terms

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually crop the `Bitmap` after capture.

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(
  source = originalBitmap,
  x = rect.topLeft.x,
  y = rect.topLeft.y,
  width = newWidth,
  height = newHeight
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am getting this error after implementing this, y + height must be <= bitmap.height(), looking for the solution

Comment: This means the height of your cropping rect exceeds the height of the bitmap if calculated from the height at which we start cropping. Make sure all the heights and dimensions are in the same units, dp or px as convention.