# How to create blur cameraview with square cutout for QR Scanner in compose?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using `AndroidView` to use `PreviewView` in compose but Modifier constraints are not working on it. I tried several ways but couldn't achieve the blur and the centre cutout part.
I tried to create `Box` over `AndroidView` with some alpha but not able to figure out how to create the cutout in centre with corner radius.

Any suggestion with or without blur, can use alpha overlay instead of blur.

[image: Expectations]

Comment: This might not be exactly what you are looking for but i think it might help you to understand how to achieve without blur. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533016/how-can-i-achieve-the-below-layout-in-jetpack-compose?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: How did you achieve the blur effect? I'm trying to do it myself, but can't get it to work